# How to select a group by members list

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is a SQL question.

Conditions:

```
1. We have a list (table) of users  
2. Each user can belong to one or more Groups
```

So, there are three tables like these:

```
Users [userId, userName]
Groups [groupId, groupName]
UserGroups [userId, groupId]
```

The goal is to determine a group by exact list of its members.

For example, we have a query to get a group (if any) for two specific users. Our goal is to determine (`SELECT`) this one specific group with only those two members in it.

The obvious brute solution is to calculate and store a hash for each group's list of members, then calculate a hash for users list in query, and compare them. But it's too complicated, since requires a recalculation of all hashes when user is  deleted from DB, or a new user is added to some group.

Maybe there are some comparison clauses I don't know in SQL?

#### Update.

Here is the solution I've made, basing on the answers:

```
WITH _userIds AS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')),
_groupIds AS (
    SELECT groupId FROM userGroups WHERE userId IN _userIds
    GROUP BY groupId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _userIds))
SELECT groupId FROM userGroups WHERE groupId IN _groupIds
GROUP BY groupId
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _userIds);
```

It's based mostly on the accepted answer and does the same things.

Comment: By "only those two memebers" means nobody less and nobody else right?

Comment: Those 2 users are in a separated table? In an array as parameters?

Comment: This is known as "exact relational division" if you're googling

Comment: @Juan correct. the goal is to find a group by it's exact members list.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan thanks for hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about selecting all the members with an IN and counting?

```
SELECT groupID
FROM UserGroups
WHERE groupID IN(
  SELECT groupID
  FROM UserGroups
  WHERE userid IN (<list of all userids here>)
  GROUP BY groupID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = <count of userid list here>
) GROUP BY groupID
HAVING COUNT(*) = <count of userid list here>
```

Why do the count and group by twice? Well..

The inner one should select all groups that have all the listed users.. I.e. if you have 5 users in your IN list, and you have a group that only contains 4 of the 5, it is eliminated at this step.. But what about groups that have 6 members, 5 of whom are in the list? That's what the outer group by is for; the inner has prepared a "list of groups that definitely have these 5 members in, but maybe some additional members" and then the outer grouping collects together groups what ONLY have 5 members, which must be the 5 members in the IN list. If a group has 6 members it is eliminated

Note; I don't use or run SQLite, this is just using generic ansi SQL. I checked that SQLite can do HAVING - seems it can; if you get any errors or functionality problems with this query let me know via comment

Here's an alternative way of doing the same thing, using a JOIN instead of IN (long lists of IN can lead to performance problems in some DBs):

```
SELECT
  groupID
FROM
  UserGroups ug
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT groupID countof FROM UserGroups GROUP BY groupID HAVING COUNT(*) = <list length>) countedGroups
  ON ug.groupID = countedGroups.GroupID
WHERE
  ug.UserID IN (<list of user ids>) 
GROUP BY groupID
HAVING COUNT(*) = <list length>
```

Comment: Wow, that's perfect! Thank you. (Actually wrote this for your first unedited post :) ). Sqlite support `HAVE` for sure.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select groupid
from usergroups
group by groupid
having sum(case when userid not in ( <members you care about> ) then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       count(*) = <# members you care about>;
```

If you don't want to count members explicitly, you can use a subquery:

```
with u as (
      select 1 as userid union all
      select . . .
     )
select groupid
from usergroups ug join
     u
     on ug.userid = u.userid
group by groupid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from u);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the member to look for in a table is as simple as try to join them with the `userGroups` table and count how many match you get.

```
SELECT U.groupId
FROM UserGroups U
LEFT JOIN searchUsers S
  ON U.userId = S.userId
GROUP BY U.groupId
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(S.userId)
```